# Pagination widget does not work

Tags: pagination, widget, typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

This is what I get when using the fluid pagination widget.

1. it try to jump to the 2nd page but without any success
2. it generates this URL which look like this

http://example.com/news-stories/essen/?tx__%5B%40widget_0%5D%5BcurrentPage%5D=2

This URL above won't work. It is generated by the Tag

I am using the Menu Type "Thumbnail" of **Bootstrap Package**. And this is the fluid tag which i use to generate it:

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{menu}" as="paginatedItems" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 6, insertAbove: 1, insertBelow: 1}">
        <f:for each="{paginatedItems}" as="page">

                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
                        <f:link.page pageUid="{page.data.uid}" title="{page.data.title}" class="thumbnail" data="{equalheight: 'item', toggle: 'tooltip'}">
                            <div class="thumbnail-image">
                                <f:if condition="{page.files.0}">
                                    <f:if condition="{page.files.0.type} == 2">
                                        <f:media file="{page.files.0}" width="{settings.media.width}" height="{settings.media.height}" />
                                    </f:if>
                                </f:if>
                            </div>
                            <div class="thumbnail-caption">
                                <f:if condition="{page.data.title}">
                                    <h3><f:format.crop maxCharacters="{settings.title.crop}">{page.data.title}</f:format.crop></h3>
                                </f:if>
                                <f:if condition="{page.data.abstract}">
                                    <p><f:format.crop maxCharacters="{settings.abstract.crop}">{page.data.abstract}</f:format.crop></p>
                                </f:if>
                            </div>
                        </f:link.page>
                    </div>
        </f:for>
    </f:widget.paginate>
```

Can anybody help to make the pagination work, should I configure something?

Comment: Your plugin name is missing. Show us your fluid tag for the widget viewhelper!

Answer (score -1):

The paginate widget needs a plugin context to work. Even the backend paginate widget needs a controller to function. It would be a nice feature to have paginate widget work with menus and other arrays.